# Ctrl + c using sshj

Tags: java, sshj

I am using sshj to communicate from my java application

```
try {
            final Command cmd = session.exec("tcpdump <some command>");
            System.out.println(IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString());
            cmd.join(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("\n** exit status: " + cmd.getExitStatus());
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
```

This works like charm, now once i want to kill this process (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) using same sshj. I have no clue, Is there any command to do it?

Comment: Looks like this post has some info. Can open your command as a pseudo terminal and then send ctrl+c. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330692/killing-a-process-through-sshj

Comment: Try `session.allocateDefaultPTY()` as indicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19985859/2346823